# My php variable reverts back to original value after resetting its value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page that interacts with a database. I am trying to display data from the database as options for a user to select. I am trying to record which option a user selects but the variable I use ($a_game_id) to record which button is clicked gets reverted back to its original value after submitting another form. I have tried declaring the variable as global within the loop and using session variables.

```
$a_game_id = 9;//starting value - it changes from 9 as desired, but reverts back when another form is submitted

$sql = "SELECT * FROM nbagames WHERE date = '" .$date ."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    global $a_game_id;
    // output data of each row
    $results = $conn->query($sql);
    $resultset = array();
    while($a_row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        $resultset[] = $a_row;
    }
    foreach ($resultset as $row){
        echo "<form action='display_lines.php' method='POST'>

            <br>" . $row["away"] . "   " .  $row['away_spread'] . "---TOTAL AVAILABLE:  " . $away_sum_array[$row['game_id']].

            " <input type='submit' value='Bet " . $row['away'] ."' name='" . $row['game_id']."A' />

             at " .  $row["home"] . "   " . $row['home_spread'] . "---TOTAL AVAILABLE:  " .$home_sum_array[$row['game_id']]. " 
               <input type='submit' value= 'Bet " . $row['home'] ."' name='" . $row['game_id']."H' /> "  . $row['date'] .  "
            </form>
            <br>";

        ///HERE $a_game_id has gets the desired value

        if(isset($_POST[$row['game_id'].'H'])){
            $a_game_id = intval($row['game_id']);
        }else if(isset($_POST[$row['game_id'].'A'])){
            $a_game_id = intval($row['game_id']);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<br> 0 results";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM nbagames WHERE date = '" .$date ."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         if(isset($_POST[strval($row['game_id']).'H'])){
            echo '<h3>'.$row['game_id'].'<br>';
            echo $row['home'].'   '.$row['home_spread'].'<br>';
            $team = $row['home'];
            $team_spread = $row['away_spread']; 
            echo '<form action="display_lines.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="new_bet_amount" placeholder="Enter Bet Amount">
                    <input type="submit" name="new_bet_submit" value="Submit Bet">
                </form></h3>';
         }
         else if(isset($_POST[strval($row['game_id']).'A'])){
            echo '<h3>' .$row['game_id'].'<br>';
            echo $row['away'].'   '.$row['away_spread'].'<br>';
            $team = $row['away'];
            $team_spread = $row['away_spread'];
            echo '<form action="display_lines.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="new_bet_amount" placeholder="Enter Bet Amount">
                    <input type="submit" name="new_bet_submit" value="Submit Bet">
                </form></h3>';
         }
 }


if(isset($_POST['new_bet_submit'])){

    //HERE $a_game_id reverts back to its original value which is undesirable

    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO placed_bets (user_id, game_id, bet_amount, game_date) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '".$a_game_id."', '".$_POST['new_bet_amount']."', '".$date."')";
    echo $a_game_id.'<br>';
    if ($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
            echo "<br><h3>BET PLACED SUCCESSFULLY</h3><br>";
        } else {
            echo '<h3>Error placing bet<br>';
            echo $conn->error;
            echo '</h3>';
        }
 }
```

Thank you for taking a look

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Why are you using `global` here? That's a sign something's not right. This is a simple function, it shouldn't need that kind of thing.

Comment: I fail to understand what you're trying to do here. I have a feeling you're going about a task in a completely wrong way. Please try to explain the big picture (what the page is actually doing, in steps).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "when I make another request all my global variables get reset?" If so, *yes*, that's how they work. Each request is completely independent of others. They do not share variables or other data. All you get is what's in `$_SESSION`, `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

If you need to persist between requests you *must* put that in the session, the database, or something persistent.

If you're used to code where the process persists and the variables stick, like in client-side situations, that's a mode of thinking you need to completely abandon.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been stuck for two days and using $_SESSION made it persist.

Comment: As a note, if you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.